# Handling special characters in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Core app, that listens for a request from a third-party API, basically just a controller with the endpoint. This third-party API sends data in a query string, but one of the parameter names starts from `#`.

```
[HttpGet("auth")]
public IActionResult Auth([FromQuery] string access_token, [FromQuery] int expires_in)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

This parameter is an access token value, so within URL it looks like this:

`https://baseUrl?#access_token=something`

So I need to declare it like this:

`...([FromQuery] string #access_token,...`

But we cannot use `#` in variable names, so how I should map this query parameter to my method parameter? Thanks.

Comment: # values aren't passed to the server. So it won't be there to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **#** is not included, **it's just an indicator for repleaceable content**.
 Faced a similar mistake with mongodb connect api, when they used to have # in their connection strings.

you can't have an # in the name of a variable/query string, it's just an indicator.

in third party api now, they use **<>** to mean replaceable content/values
like <access_token=something> or <access_token>.